# The hair displacements differs in object mode from those in particle mode

Tags: particles, hair

[image]

the upper image is in particle mode and the lower image is in object mode.
the displacements of the hair vastly differs. How do I fix it and let those hairs in object mode lie exactly on where the hairs in particles mode is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to go on edit mode of your hair object (the screw one) and rotate it in one of the three axis. This will rotate all the particles as well.

Hope it helps.